# Table cells image manipulation with jquery

Tags: jquery

Here's the nice and interesting problem I'm trying to figure out:

I have a table, containing 3 columns, and 8 rows. Table is generated via PHP, dynamically. Each td has a button in it with id 1,2 or 3, marking columns. Each button has 3 states/styles - Normal, clicked and hover (all different styles, 9 styles total).

So far I have managed to give each separated cell normal and hover style, via css, and I've created a jquery script to change class of clicked cell to its clicked style. Problem is, when I set cell style within one row, I want the two remaining cells in that row to be back to normal style:

left-normal **middle-clicked** right-normal
**left-clicked** middle-normal right-normal
left-normal middle-normal **right-clicked**
...

But only in THAT row.

This is my code so far:

```
function chooseItem(){

var left = $('#table td button#1');
    var middle = $('#table td button#2');
var right = $('#table td button#3');

        left.click(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('LeftNormal');
            $(this).addClass('LeftClicked');        
        })  

        right.click(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('RightNormal');
            $(this).addClass('RightClicked');         
        })  

         midle.click(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('MidleNormal');
            $(this).addClass('MidleClicked');           
        })
};
```

I have red a lot of related questions here, but no one had a similar problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show a simple, minimal, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've got so far?

Comment: I'll try to do that, but this is already a very simplified question :) That is the only thing left that bothers me, whole application is much more complex, so I don't know whether to rewrite the whole thing to show you, or just to give you  the link to App...?

Comment: Just show the minimal amount of code that you have that reproduces the problem you currently have, and are trying to solve. I'd imagine this would be the table, and the JavaScript with which you're trying to show the states/styles of the clicked cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this ?

```
   var $table = $('table');
   $table.find('button').click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('selected').parent().siblings().find('button').removeClass('selected');
   });​
```

**Click to see in action** : **http://jsfiddle.net/8qLpm/**

Comment: I'll try to implement your solution. But you are using only one class, and I need a specific class for each button in one row. That is why my buttons have IDs. Thank you very much anyway, and I hope whis will work.

Comment: why do you need all 3 classe ? if just for css reason you can detect 3 types: 1) Default, 2) Hover, 3), or there is another reason to use all 3 ?

Comment: Because I use completely different images. Didn't wanted to bother you with my whole problem, because it's to complex for quick solution. So I did my best to explain only that one part that is giving me the biggest headache.

Comment: Based on your proposition, I have implemented the solution a while ago (finaly found a bit of time). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function chooseItem(){

var left = $('#table td button1.left');
    var middle = $('#table td button2.middle');
var right = $('#table td button3.right');

        left.click(function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('button').removeClass('LeftNormal');
            $(this).addClass('LeftClicked');        
        })  

        right.click(function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('button').removeClass('RightNormal');
            $(this).addClass('RightClicked');         
        })  

         midle.click(function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('button').removeClass('MidleNormal');
            $(this).addClass('MidleClicked');           
        })
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your modification will actually do anything. I've tried to do what you've suggested, but it just made my existing code stopped working.

Comment: I've changed your declarations since I thought they indicated that you have repeated ids. Try changing it back but remember to avoid giving two elements the same id, use classes instead. The code is simply removing the class from all buttons in the row, before adding it to the clicked button. I hope that's what you want.